# Redirecting all 404 requests to / in S3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to setup S3 to host my static content. I've been following the documentation on AWS website. So far, I managed to see the web page loaded successfully by entering the endpoint of the bucket:

```
http://my-bucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

But since this is a single page application and routes are handled inside the web page (it's implemented using React), I need all the URLs pointing to non-existing pages to be redirected to `/`. So I configured the bucket's *Redirection rules* like this:

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyWith>/</ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

But the problem is that when I open the URL:

```
http://my-bucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/logon
```

I face `403 Forbidden`. It seems to me that AWS is blocking the URL since it is not public but how can I make an object public when it does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out what I was missing was granting the public access to listing the items in the bucket. But then I realized redirecting is not what I need. So I asked a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800647/returning-index-html-for-all-the-404-requests-on-s3-instead-of-redirecting).